# passing function parameters without type, then declare pointers to variables with same names

Tags: c, parameters

I was reading through [GNU C library - Date-time - Data & Functions](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html#SEC316)
and came across this function definition:

```
int timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
 struct timeval *result, *x, *y;
{
    //do stuff
    return result;
}
```

I have never come across this argument passing before. 
-There is not type for the variables within the parenthesis ().
-OK the type "struct timeval" comes later, but using the same variable names?

Is the above entirely equivalent to

```
int struct_timeval(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *x, struct timeval *y){

    //do stuff
}
```

or not?

Comment: It is old style known as K&R style.There are lots of duplicate of this type of question on SO.Please refer Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it is the old style of function declaration. It uses an identifier list in the declaration.

This kind of declaration is not equivalent to function prototypes. With a prototype, function arguments are converted to the type of parameters as if by assignment but without prototype default argument promotion occurs.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. "argument promotion"?

Comment: @nass in the general case, it means arguments of type narrower than `int` (like `char`, `short`, ...) are converted to `int` and `float` is converted to  `double`.